# Print table display text header and footer

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

Im having problem on how to add text header and footer when I print data table on html. I have already title on header but it seems that the default javascript on my template recognized the <title  </title tags in my html. Can anyone suggest or provide solution on this problem? or Thank you in advance

[image]

> ENTIRE HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
@media screen
{
.noPrint{}
.titles{display:none;}
.footer{display:none;}
}
@media print
{
.noPrint{display:none;}
.title{}
.footer{}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="printDiv();">Print it</button>
  <table class="report-container" name="table" id="table"  >
    <thead class="report-header">
  <th colspan="9"><div class="titles">Title Header <br></div></th>
   <tr>
     <td>ID Number</td>
     <td>Name</td>
     <td>Barangay</td>
     <td>Sex</td>
     <td>Sector</td>
     <td>Amount</td>
     <td>Signature/thumb</td>
     <td>ID &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
     <td>Date Received</td>
   </tr>
   </thead>
  <tfoot>
   <tr>
    <td colspan=9><div class="footer">Title Footer</div></td>
   </tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody class="report-content">
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </body>
    <script ="text/javascript">

    function printDiv() {
     var divToPrint = document.getElementById('table');
     var htmlToPrint = '' +
    '<style type="text/css">' +
        'table td {' +
    'border:1px solid #dddddd;' +
    'padding:8px;' +
    '}' +

    'table  {' +
    'border-collapse: collapse;' +
    'width: 100%;' +
    '}' +
    '</style>';
    htmlToPrint += divToPrint.outerHTML;
    newWin = window.open("");
    newWin.document.write(htmlToPrint);
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close();
   }
   </script>
```

Comment: By design, the `thead` and `tfoot` parts of a `table` object should print out on every page that the table appears.  It looks like you have already got a `thead` section there to show the column headings.  You could just add in a `tr` row above that and, using `colspan` cover all of the columns with one `th` tag - this would then contain your heading.

Comment: @ATD thank you for your response , I added table above but can you help me where should I add colspan? on tr? thank you

Answer (score 1):

Without the styling, I can't see if it exactly matches what you are trying to achieve, but you can check the styling later.

The basic structure of the `thead` tag should be something like:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th colspan=9>This should display on print</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>ID Number</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Barangay</th>
    <th>Sex</th>
    <th>Sector</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Signature/thumb</th>
    <th >ID &nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
    <th>Date Received</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=9>Text for the footer goes here</td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
```

In your table you have 9 columns, so the title `th` tag needs to span all 9.  This is done by adding `colspan=9` into the `th` element itself.

The footer should be added in a similar way.  Note that `tfoot` MUST be entered immediately after `thead` and BEFORE any `tbody` tags

(updated to include `tfoot`)

Comment: Great idea, I already use it but do you have idea why the title header and footer keeps repeating on every pages when prints I just want to display title at the top of the page and display the footer at the end of the print page. thanks for your response please see my updated code in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/k9svqa43/#&togetherjs=o1FFJ8tVzS

Comment: I can't use the functionality on that to print.  I've copied the code into a new HTML file and the print preview of that does what I expect it to do.  The headers print at the top of the table on the first page and the top of that part of the table that appears on the second page.  The footer appears at the bottom of table on the first page and at the end of the table on the second page.  Which bit don't you want to print?

Comment: thank you for your response I have updated my html above , I want to print all data of my table , but I want to print  the header title at the top of my first page and also the footer print only at the last page . Currently my code above the headers and footers display of each every page when prints it

Comment: But, do you want the header to repeat on every page?

Comment: thanks for your response, No I just want to print  header only in first page and the footer print only last page please help

Comment: So, **one** header and **one** footer, no matter how many pages the table prints on?